# Select a Count of all the records and a count of all completed records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some row data like this...

```
ID   ParentID    IsCompleted
5    300         1
10   300         1
15   300         0
20   200         1
25   200         0
```

I would like to do a query against this dataset and return something like...

```
ParentID    Total   TotalCompleted
300         3       2
200         2       1
```

I have no idea how to even ask this question so my apologies if its too easy. I did some research and thought maybe I needed a correlated query but in reading and playing with some queries I could not get it to work. Some direction would be insanely helpful

Thanks!

** NOTE **
The IsCompleted column is a bit data type, and thus SQL server will throw an "Operand data type bit is invalid for sum operator" error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `COUNT` and `SUM` functions with `GROUP BY`.

**Query**

```
select [ParentID], 
count(*) as [Total], 
sum(cast([IsCompleted] as int)) as [TotalCompleted]
from [your_table_name]
group by [ParentID];
```

Comment: I am sorry, i forgot to mention the IsCompleted column is a bit, data type. because so, i am recieving a "Operand data type bit is invalid for sum operator"

Comment: Just wanted to add that the backticks (`) before and after the column names/aliases are not required, but they will still work. Also the AS is optional, but it's recommended because it makes it clear that the next word is a column alias and not just a missed column :)

Comment: awesome thanks! i just came across this article as well. https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/08/04/sql-server-fix-error-8117-operand-data-type-bit-is-invalid-for-sum-operator/ which apparently does the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: @ZackSnyder : So, are you using `sql server`?

Comment: Sometimes I find the voting/accepting in SO frustrating :).

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `GROUP BY` and aggregation functions

```
 SELECT ParentId,
     count(*) total,
     sum(iscompleted) totalCompleted
 FROM yourtab
 GROUP BY ParentId
```

**EDIT:**

```
 SELECT ParentId,
     count(*) total,
     sum(CASE WHEN iscompleted THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalCompleted
 FROM yourtab
 GROUP BY ParentId
```

Comment: You're missing `as` on this line `sum(iscompleted) totalCompleted`. Wanderer's answer above is correct (variable names) and displays in the format requested by the poster.

Comment: @Bejasc `as` is optional

Comment: Are you trying to say Optional? Obligatory means it is required.

Comment: @bejasc true, my SQL is better than my english ;)